No internet connection when sharing WiFi connection to devices using USB LAN on OSX Sonoma 14.4
A MacBook Pro connects via Wifi to an iPhone to access the internet using en0 with the IP 172.20.10.7. An Ethernet connection via USB has en6 and is manually set to the IP 192.168.10.100. Internet sharing is on with "Share your connection from:" WiFi "To devices using" USB 10/100/1000 LAN. Firewall is off. Devices connected to 192.168.10.* can ping 192.168.10.100 and each other, but can not ping any internet address.
netstat -nr shows
192.168.10         link#13            UCS                   en6      !   
192.168.10.23      90:9:d0:0:a:68     UHLWIi                en6   1150
192.168.10.25      ac:87:a3:27:90:57  UHLWIi                en6   1097
192.168.10.100/32  link#13            UCS                   en6      !  

Would anybody know how to get internet access through USB LAN when tethering to the iPhone via WiFi?

I'm pretty sure macOS's Internet Sharing feature has a hardcoded private subnet it uses. I think it doesn't pay any attention to any IP address that was already present on the downstream interface (i.e. the "To devices using:" interface). So you might want to try ditching that static IP config and just let Internet Sharing pick the subnet and serve out its private addresses via the DHCP server functionality that's built into the Internet Sharing feature.
